# method does not override or implement a method

Tags: java, android, methods

Last 2 methods in my code gave error `client.get(WEATHER_URL, params,  new JsonHttpResponseHandler(){` after this line of code (2 `@Override` parts). Is it just not understanding method or something?

```
final String WEATHER_URL = "http://api./openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather";


final String APP_ID = "e72ca729af228beabd5d20e3b7749713";
//setting variables
final int REQUEST_CODE =123;
long MIN_TIME = 5000;
float MIN_DISTANCE = 1000;

// Set Location-Provider:
String LOCATION_PROVIDER = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
LocationManager mLocationManager;
LocationListener mLocationListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.weather_layout);

    mButton_change = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.change_button);
    mButton_change.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, change_the_location.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d("asdasd", " asd");
    getWeatherForCurrentLocation();
}

private void getWeatherForCurrentLocation() {

    mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    mLocationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            String longitude = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
            String latitude = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());

            Log.d("Clima", "OnLocationcahnge() recieved");

            RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
            params.put("lat", latitude);
            params.put("long", longitude);
            params.put("appid", APP_ID);
            letsDoSomeNetworking(params);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

            Log.d("Clima", "OnProviderDisabled recieved");

        }
    };

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.

      ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},REQUEST_CODE);
        return;
    }
    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LOCATION_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME, MIN_DISTANCE, mLocationListener);
    }

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE){
    if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        Log.d("Clima", "Requestpermissionresult()   ");
    getWeatherForCurrentLocation();
    }else{

       Log.d(" CLiama", "Permission denied!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    }

}
}

        private void letsDoSomeNetworking(RequestParams params){
            AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

            client.get(WEATHER_URL, params,  new JsonHttpResponseHandler(){

                @Override
                public void OnSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response){

                    Log.d("Clima", "Here is JSONTEXT:  " +  response.toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void OnFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable e, JSONObject response){
                    Log.e("Clima", "Fail to response" + e.toString());
                    Log.d("Clima", "Status Code " + statusCode);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            });

        }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that you are improting the right classes:

```
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.loopj.android.http.JsonHttpResponseHandler;
import org.json.JSONObject;
```

This should be the correct override:

```
client.get("......", new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) 
    {
        super.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, response);

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, JSONObject errorResponse) {
        super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, throwable, errorResponse);
    }
});
```

(Seems it's just the capital "O" in "OnSuccess" and "OnFailure")